# Disable links for the current url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

O.K. I think that's an easy one! 
I have a ViewMasterPage with some links on it (Home/About/Login/ etc). What I want to achieve is simply have the link disabled when it's referral url is already opened (i.e. if the current url is /Register then the Register link should be disabled .. easy hah!?) 
As I don't like to write a lot of in-line coding inside of my views, I end up extending HtmlHelper with some extension methods (just to keep the code in .cs files) and in my views I call these methods, here's my register method as an example:

```
 public static string Register (this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        TagBuilder builder ;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(MainLinks.Register.ToUpperInvariant()))
            return MainLinks.Register; // will return the string "Register"

        builder = new TagBuilder("a");
        builder.InnerHtml = MainLinks.Register;
        builder.AddCssClass("register");
        builder.Attributes.Add("href", "/register/");
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Though this works, it still has two problems:

1. The hard coded string values of the urls (specially for the home link as I compare the AbslouteUri with "http://www.mysite.com/")
2. My programming instinct doesn't like it, I feel it should be much simpler than that.

Any ideas!

Ps: No javascipt allowed! It's a javascript-free version of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see too much wrong with this, it's clear to see what it does and it works.  However, it's probably better to make it a bit more reusable as I can imagine you repeat yourself a bit with the other links. Maybe something like:

```
public static string RenderLink(this HtmlHelper html, string text, string url, object htmlAttr) {
  if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith(url, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
    return text;  //comparison excludes the domain
  }
  TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
  tag.SetInnerText(text);
  tag.Attributes.Add("href", url);
  //... add attributes parsed as htmlAttr here
  return tag.ToString();
}
```

Then add your links to your view like:

```
<%= Html.RenderLink("Register", "/register/", new { @class="register"}) %>
<%= Html.RenderLink("Account", "/account/", new { @class="account"}) %>
```

If you wanted to get away from the hard coded domain, then using *Request.Url.AbsolutePath* instead of *AbsoluteUri* as above achieves that.

The alternative would be to parse the current page information in the model from the controller, maybe like *ViewData.Model.CurrentPage = "Register";*, but I wouldn't advise you doing that as I don't see it being the job of the controller in this case.

Comment: Thanks DaveG! I will try to keep it DRY! I will wait some more time here, maybe someone proposes a simpler idea! Thanks again.

Comment: Oh I almost forgot to mention it .. +1 :)